# Expand a div on click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

My problem is fairly simple for many of you.
I want to expand the div(onClick) to fit the outer div and it should completely cover all the other three divs.(not fullscreen)

I am trying to do this using the following code but the entire structure of page gets disturbed when i try to do this.

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .toggler
    {
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 270px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .newClass
    {
        height: 500px;
        width: 290px;
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 10000px;
        float: left;

    }

    .divClass
    {
        float: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 50px;
        width: 500px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div1').click(function() {
    $('#div1').toggleClass('newClass');
    });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table width="100%">
    <tr style="height: 100%;">
        <td style="width: 30%; height: 500px;">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 70%; height: 500px;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
                <table style="height: 500px; width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="toggler">
                            <div id="div1" style="background-color: Black;">
                                Hello World!
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%" class="toggler">
                            <div id="div2" style="background-color: Blue; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%" class="toggler">
                            <div id="div3" style="background-color: Red; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%" class="toggler">
                            <div id="div4" style="background-color: Maroon; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

What exactly is the problem with my code???? please help..

**Note**: I've also tried addClass and removeClass methods.. No good results...

Comment: it should cover all the div? you want the 3 divs not to show when the onclick div is bigger right? btw why are they in a table?

Comment: and z-index doesnt use px

Comment: I need to apply this function to all the other three divs... and yes, you are right, i dont want to show other three divs when any ne of them is zoomed...

Comment: and it works same even if i dont use px in z-index.. :(

Comment: do you really need it to be in a table?

Comment: not really.. but they are to be arranged in this fashion...

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4L5fw/

Comment: or something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4L5fw/1/

Comment: I don't have a lot of time so please respond quickly

Comment: Yes exacltly..! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something like this. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4L5fw/2/

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="black"></div>
    <div class="blue "></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
.black{
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
}
.blue{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: blue;
}

.red{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: red;
}
.green{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: green;
}

div{
    float: left;
}


.active{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}​
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper div').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().not(this).toggleClass('hide');
    });
});
```

​

Comment: Thank you man.. The best and the most optimised code I've ever seen..! Thank a lot..!

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work fine.

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .toggler
    {
        max-width: 500px;
        max-height: 270px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .newClass
    {
        height: 500px;
        width: 290px;
        display: inline-block;
        z-index: 10000px;
        float: left;

    }

    .divClass
    {
        float: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 50px;
        width: 500px;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div1').click(function() {
    $('#div1').toggleClass('newClass');
    });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table width="100%">
    <tr style="height: 100%;">
        <td style="width: 30%; height: 500px;">
        </td>
        <td style="width: 70%; height: 500px;">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 500px;">
                <table style="height: 500px; width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="toggler">
                            <div id="div1" style="background-color: Black;">
                                Hello World!
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%" class="toggler">
                            <div id="div2" style="background-color: Blue; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%" class="toggler">
                            <div id="div3" style="background-color: Red; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%" class="toggler">
                            <div id="div4" style="background-color: Maroon; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>​
```

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/3tkpa/

If you click on the black div, it expands.  When it is expanded and clicked, it collapse.

Comment: When you use jQuery, why don't you simply use `.toggle()` instead of making it unneeded complicated by changing a class back and forth?

Comment: How can i use that? Without changing the class?? actually, i didnt really get you! :(

Comment: and @malkassem... the whole table structure gets disturbed when i click on the div.. i dont want that.. i want to resize the smaller div to full size div.. covering all other three divs..